# SCCM licensing on a Hyper-V cluster

Tags: hyper-v, licensing, sccm-2012-r2

We have two Microsoft Private Clouds: one consists of 8 nodes (each with two processors) and the other consists of 4 nodes (each with two processors). Call them Private Cloud A and Private Cloud B. Each node is currently licensed on our EA with a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacentre license.

Some production services are hosted on A, with DR instances for those services existing on B (i.e. SQL availability group with primary on A, one secondary on A (for HA) and one secondary on B (for DR), Exchange cross-site DAG). We also have some production services running on B, with DR instances running on A.

Private Cloud A hosts about 70 VM's (95% Windows Server 2012, rest are Linux based) and Private Cloud B hosts about 30 VM's.

We'd like to implement SCCM (more specifically, SCVMM) to help us manage the virtual environment (which is currently done mostly through Powershell scripts and manual intervention on Failover Cluster Manager and Hyper-V console).

How should we license SCCM 2012 R2 in this environment? Would I need to purchase a Datacentre License for each of the 12 hosts (which would be an exorbitant amount)? Or, do I only license one host with a Standard license, and host all my VM's that run SCCM components on that one host? Or should I rather put down a physical machine to host these components, and license with a Standard license?

Comment: True... just read the link.

Answer (score 0):

This [SC License Datasheet](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi0jfvsrd_OAhXDthQKHfKJAfIQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fb%2F4%2Fa%2Fb4a98a4e-2f43-489d-8761-5362c8c2c328%2Fsystem_center_2012_r2_licensing_datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGCWVssyh181rq0vKboWXrsmP7xHg&sig2=CHKxAgLS3vzSneA4si0nFg&bvm=bv.130731782,bs.1,d.bGs&cad=rja)  document is a good reference point.

A premises: you cannot buy SCVMM as single product, you must be buy all the suite.

You need to purchase a SC Datacenter License for each physical nodes, this allow you manage both all Hosts and all Guests.